# extra space at bottom of page?

Tags: html, css

styling of buttons with css is causing extra space at the bottom of my page.

this is the part causing it:

```
.contact-links {
        position: relative;
        bottom: 150px;
        font-size: 1.0em;
    }

    .linkedin-button {
        display: inline-block;
        background: url('{{ url_for('static', filename='linkedin-logo.png') }}') no-repeat;
        background-size: contain; /* Ensure the logo fits inside the button */
        width: 150px; /* Adjust as needed */
        height: 150px; /* Adjust as needed */
        text-indent: -9999px; /* Hide text content */
        overflow: hidden; /* Hide overflow */
        position: relative;
        right: 50px;
    }
    .github-button {
        display: inline-block;
        background: url('{{ url_for('static', filename='github-logo.png') }}') no-repeat;
        background-size: contain; /* Ensure the logo fits inside the button */
        width: 150px; /* Adjust as needed */
        height: 150px; /* Adjust as needed */
        text-indent: -9999px; /* Hide text content */
        overflow: hidden; /* Hide overflow */
        position: relative;
        left: 50px;

    }

    .email-button {
    display: inline-block;
    background: url('{{ url_for('static', filename='email.png') }}') no-repeat;
    background-size: contain; /* Ensure the logo fits inside the button */
    width: 60px; /* Adjust as needed (half of the original width) */
    height: 150px; /* Adjust as needed (half of the original height) */
    text-indent: -9999px; /* Hide text content */
    overflow: hidden; /* Hide overflow */

    }
```

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Playfair Display';
  src: url('{{ url_for('static', filename='Playfair_Display/PlayfairDisplay-VariableFont_wght.ttf') }}') format('truetype');
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'League Spartan';
  src: url('{{ url_for('static', filename='LeagueSpartan-VariableFont_wght.ttf') }}') format('truetype');
}

body {
    color: #d3d3d3
}

a {
    color: #d3d3d3;
}

h1 {
    font: 2em 'Playfair Display', sans-serif;
    color: #d3d3d3;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

p {
    font: 1.5em 'League Spartan', sans-serif;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.contact-links {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 150px;
    font-size: 1.0em;
}

.linkedin-button {
    display: inline-block;
    background: url('{{ url_for('static', filename='linkedin-logo.png') }}') no-repeat;
    background-size: contain; /* Ensure the logo fits inside the button */
    width: 150px; /* Adjust as needed */
    height: 150px; /* Adjust as needed */
    text-indent: -9999px; /* Hide text content */
    overflow: hidden; /* Hide overflow */
    position: relative;
    right: 50px;
}
.github-button {
    display: inline-block;
    background: url('{{ url_for('static', filename='github-logo.png') }}') no-repeat;
    background-size: contain; /* Ensure the logo fits inside the button */
    width: 150px; /* Adjust as needed */
    height: 150px; /* Adjust as needed */
    text-indent: -9999px; /* Hide text content */
    overflow: hidden; /* Hide overflow */
    position: relative;
    left: 50px;
}

.email-button {
  display: inline-block;
  background: url('{{ url_for('static', filename='email.png') }}') no-repeat;
  background-size: contain; /* Ensure the logo fits inside the button */
  width: 60px; /* Adjust as needed (half of the original width) */
  height: 150px; /* Adjust as needed (half of the original height) */
  text-indent: -9999px; /* Hide text content */
  overflow: hidden; /* Hide overflow */
}


.custom-hr {
    border-top: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
    height: 250px; /* Adjust the height as needed */
    margin-top: 10px; /* Add margin to separate the line from content */
    margin-bottom: 20px; /* Add margin to separate the line from content */
}

.contact-form {
    background-color: white;
    padding: 30px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: none; /* Removed box shadow */
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 200px;
}

.contact-form label {
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: black;
    text-shadow: none; /* Removed text shadow */
    font-family: 'League Spartan', sans-serif;
}

.contact-form input,
.contact-form textarea {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 12px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 1px solid #ced4da;
    border-radius: 4px;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: 'League Spartan', sans-serif; /* Use the same font as other elements */
    transition: border-color 0.3s;
}

.contact-form textarea {
    resize: vertical;
}

.contact-form input:focus,
.contact-form textarea:focus {
    border-color: #007bff;
}

.contact-form button {
    background-color: #007bff;
    color: white;
    padding: 12px 20px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: 'League Spartan', sans-serif; /* Use the same font as other elements */
    transition: background-color 0.3s;
}

.contact-form button:hover {
    background-color: #0056b3;
}
```

```html
<h1 style="display: flex">Contact </h1>
<div class="custom-hr"></div>

<form class="contact-form" action="/submit" method="post">
    <label for="name">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" required placeholder="Enter your name">

    <label for="email">Email:</label>
    <input type="email" id="email" name="email" required placeholder="Enter your email">

    <label for="message">Message:</label>
    <textarea id="message" name="message" rows="4" required placeholder="Enter your message"></textarea>

    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
<div class="contact-links">
    <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/malikmassaquoi/" target="_blank" class="linkedin-button">LinkedIn</a>
    <a href=mailto:MalikMassaquoi@outlook.com" target="_blank" class="email-button">Email</a>
    <a href="https://github.com/SirLeekster" target="_blank" class="github-button">GitHub</a>
</div>
```

Im new to Css and html so i have no clue why its doing this

Comment: I've edited your question so that your code is now a snippet that can be run directly from your question.

Answer (score 1):

First, a minor thing: you are missing a beginning quote here:

```
<a href=mailto:MalikMassaquoi@outlook.com" target="_blank" class="email-button">Email</a>
--------^
```

That should be

```
<a href="mailto:MalikMassaquoi@outlook.com" target="_blank" class="email-button">Email</a>
```

Your main problem is that you are trying to manually position everything with `position:absolute` or `position:relative` I've commented all of that out below. Just let the elements flow naturally and the page will grow as you add elements.

Note: I had to remove the links to the fonts since you included server-side code the generate the links, which we can't get, and I am just using solid colors for the images since we don't have access to the image paths you do.

```css
body {
    color: #d3d3d3
}

a {
    color: #d3d3d3;
}

h1 {
    font: 2em 'Playfair Display', sans-serif;
    color: #d3d3d3;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

p {
    font: 1.5em 'League Spartan', sans-serif;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.contact-links {
    /*position: relative;
    bottom: 150px;*/
    font-size: 1.0em;
}

.linkedin-button {
    display: inline-block;
    background: blue;
    background-size: contain; /* Ensure the logo fits inside the button */
    width: 150px; /* Adjust as needed */
    height: 150px; /* Adjust as needed */
    text-indent: -9999px; /* Hide text content */
    overflow: hidden; /* Hide overflow */
    /*position: relative;
    right: 50px;*/
}
.github-button {
    display: inline-block;
    background: red;
    background-size: contain; /* Ensure the logo fits inside the button */
    width: 150px; /* Adjust as needed */
    height: 150px; /* Adjust as needed */
    text-indent: -9999px; /* Hide text content */
    overflow: hidden; /* Hide overflow */
    /*position: relative;
    left: 50px;*/
}

.email-button {
  display: inline-block;
  background: orange;
  background-size: contain; /* Ensure the logo fits inside the button */
  width: 60px; /* Adjust as needed (half of the original width) */
  height: 150px; /* Adjust as needed (half of the original height) */
  text-indent: -9999px; /* Hide text content */
  overflow: hidden; /* Hide overflow */
}


.custom-hr {
    border-top: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
    /*height: 250px;*/ /* Adjust the height as needed */
    margin-top: 10px; /* Add margin to separate the line from content */
    margin-bottom: 20px; /* Add margin to separate the line from content */
}

.contact-form {
    background-color: white;
    padding: 30px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: none; /* Removed box shadow */
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    /*position: relative;
    bottom: 200px;*/
}

.contact-form label {
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: black;
    text-shadow: none; /* Removed text shadow */
    font-family: 'League Spartan', sans-serif;
}

.contact-form input,
.contact-form textarea {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 12px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 1px solid #ced4da;
    border-radius: 4px;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: 'League Spartan', sans-serif; /* Use the same font as other elements */
    transition: border-color 0.3s;
}

.contact-form textarea {
    resize: vertical;
}

.contact-form input:focus,
.contact-form textarea:focus {
    border-color: #007bff;
}

.contact-form button {
    background-color: #007bff;
    color: white;
    padding: 12px 20px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: 'League Spartan', sans-serif; /* Use the same font as other elements */
    transition: background-color 0.3s;
}

.contact-form button:hover {
    background-color: #0056b3;
}
```

```html
<h1 style="display: flex">Contact </h1>
<div class="custom-hr"></div>

<form class="contact-form" action="/submit" method="post">
    <label for="name">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" required placeholder="Enter your name">

    <label for="email">Email:</label>
    <input type="email" id="email" name="email" required placeholder="Enter your email">

    <label for="message">Message:</label>
    <textarea id="message" name="message" rows="4" required placeholder="Enter your message"></textarea>

    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
<div class="contact-links">
    <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/malikmassaquoi/" target="_blank" class="linkedin-button">LinkedIn</a>
    <a href="mailto:MalikMassaquoi@outlook.com" target="_blank" class="email-button">Email</a>
    <a href="https://github.com/SirLeekster" target="_blank" class="github-button">GitHub</a>
</div>
```

---

Also, your CSS regarding those links can be simplified.

You have this that repeats a lot of stuff for each link

```css
.contact-links {
    font-size: 1.0em;
}

.linkedin-button {
    display: inline-block;
    background: url('{{ url_for('static', filename='linkedin-logo.png') }}') no-repeat;
    background-size: contain; /* Ensure the logo fits inside the button */
    width: 150px; /* Adjust as needed */
    height: 150px; /* Adjust as needed */
    text-indent: -9999px; /* Hide text content */
    overflow: hidden; /* Hide overflow */
}
.github-button {
    display: inline-block;
    background: url('{{ url_for('static', filename='github-logo.png') }}') no-repeat;
    background-size: contain; /* Ensure the logo fits inside the button */
    width: 150px; /* Adjust as needed */
    height: 150px; /* Adjust as needed */
    text-indent: -9999px; /* Hide text content */
    overflow: hidden; /* Hide overflow */
}

.email-button {
  display: inline-block;
  background: url('{{ url_for('static', filename='email.png') }}') no-repeat;
  background-size: contain; /* Ensure the logo fits inside the button */
  width: 60px; /* Adjust as needed (half of the original width) */
  height: 150px; /* Adjust as needed (half of the original height) */
  text-indent: -9999px; /* Hide text content */
  overflow: hidden; /* Hide overflow */
}
```

Since each link is an `a` tag inside of the `.contact-links` element you can just put the common/shared stuff in there, and then only specify the things that are unique to each link afterwards. See this, which will work exactly the same as the above code.

```css
.contact-links a {
    font-size: 1em;
    display: inline-block;
    background-size: contain; /* Ensure the logo fits inside the button */
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 150px; /* Adjust as needed */
    height: 150px; /* Adjust as needed */
    text-indent: -9999px; /* Hide text content */
    overflow: hidden; /* Hide overflow */
}

.linkedin-button {
  background-image: url('{{ url_for('static', filename='linkedin-logo.png') }}');
}
.github-button {
  background-image: url('{{ url_for('static', filename='github-logo.png') }}');
}
.email-button {
  background-image: url('{{ url_for('static', filename='email.png') }}');
  width: 60px;
}
```